# performing large, periodic aggregations on a data set in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection of posts that can be liked by the user. I want to calculate a 'trending' like feature, by periodically iterating over the collection of posts and assigning them each a 'trending' score. This 'trending' score will need to be calculated with some custom javascript -- not something I could do using the aggregation framework of Mongodb, I don't think.

My questions:

1) How do I iterate over the collection and perform these calculations? I could do a mapreduce, but then my 'trending' score won't be saved into the database itself, making it difficult to query.

2) How should the 'trending' score be saved? Should I alter the main database, and insert a new trending score into each of the documents themselves? Should I save a copy of the documents with the trending score in a new database?

Comment: Do you want each result to overwrite the old trending data?

Comment: Yeah, I do. Unless there would be good reason to save the old trending data.

Comment: The aggregation framework has an [$out](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage which will put the results into a collection for you, overwriting it if it exists.